# How to exclude library includes when doing rename symbol?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, refactoring

When doing **Rename Symbol** (`F2`) in C++ Visual Studio Code, IDE/plugin traverses also the standard includes (STL etc.) and it takes too long on my machine. Please, how to restrict refactoring only to non-standard project files?

- Visual Studio Code: 1.43.0
- ms-vscode.cpptools C/C++ plugin: 0.27.0-insiders2
- OS: Arch Linux 5.5.8 kernel
- Compiler: gcc 9.2.1

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct method to do so.

Workaround: Use the [side menu](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options) (textual replace)

[image: Advanced search options]

[image: search and replace diff view]

Drawback: Ctrl+F2 renames the 'symbol' in comments as well since it is a textual rename. ([ref](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11348#issuecomment-244001641))

Comment: This kind of refactoring is unfortunately no go for me :-( I am surprised that after many years of development such a fundamental feature does not work properly in VS Code / C++.

Comment: @eeq there are various bugs with this feature dude! On certain languages rename symbol has scope of only of one file.